# Ext Data Model listener

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc, extjs4.2

I'm new in ExtJS 4, and I make an extended Data Model. I want to listen model's set function. How can I make a custom listener on set, or override set with original set functions + extensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own `set` function and call `callParent`:

```
Ext.define('My.data.Model', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    set: function () {
        this.callParent(arguments); // original set functions
        console.log(arguments);     // extensions
    }
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/RyMGc/